# hd0,gpt2 not found error

Tags: boot, partitioning

System information :

- Laptop model: Victus by HP Laptop 16-e0xxx
- RAM: AMD Ryzen 7 5800H
  (16G)
- Graphics card: NVidia RTX 3050
- Current OS Windows 10
- Desired   OS Ubuntu 21.10

I have a copy of everything in a external hard drive, so if the solution is to wipe clean the hard-drive I´m willing to go that route.

I have Windows installed and want to start using Ubuntu (20.10). I got a bit carried away eliminating partitions and it seems that I eliminated the MBR, windows still starts but I have to find the EFI myself on the BIOS.

I made a bootable flashdrive using rufus but when I try to boot I get the following error:
I´m very lost and I don't know what to do.

Have in mind that I don´t have much idea so if what I have written doesn't make sense or you find that information is missing please don´t doubt on responding and ask for it. I will edit the message.
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1j0Kv.jpg)

The message that appears when I try to boot Ubuntu from the live USB is the following:

```
[ 0.2551641 ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Could not resolve symbol ISB.PCIO.GPP1.W LAN), AE_NOT FOUND (20210331/dswload2-162)
[ 0.2551771 ACPI Error: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20210331/psobject-220) 
[ 0.2555611 ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [/_SB.PC10.GPP0.VGA], AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210331/dswload2-326) 
[ 0.2555641 ACPI Error: AE ALREADY EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (202103 31/psob ject-220)
[ 0.255567] ACPI BIOS Error (bug): Failure creating named object [_SB.PCIO.G PPO.HDAU), AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20210331/dswload2-326) 
[ 0.255569] ACPI Error : AE ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (202103 31/psob ject-220)
```

Comment: Does your Windows still start? Seems some settings in Rufus were wrong.     If Windows doesn't start (because you deleted the partition for example) make a new stick on another computer. ( I use Ventoy, cannot screwup any settings. You can also use Balena Etcher. Also no settings needed. )     Can you provide some information of your hardware (motherboard, how much RAM, HDD/SSD and what version of K-/L-/X- Ubuntu are you trying to install 20.04.4/21.10)? Please edit your question with this information.

Comment: I have just updated the info. Im going to try to make a bootable usb with windows to format the hard drive using the installer.

Comment: it has not worked as i have not been able to start the iwindows installer, nor the ubuntu one

Comment: How did you make the usb-stick ? Which program did you use? Did you boot from the usb-stick and it did not work, or don't you know how to boot from usb?

Comment: For the ubuntu bootable stick I used RUFUS, for the windows bootable stick I used the native tool available on the windows webpage.  I have just managed to reset the computer and did what I asumed is a fresh windows install using the windows reset tool found in the settings. I know how to boot from a USB but it wont work (windows and ubuntu). I want to quit windows so if there is a way to fix this not using windows I will gladly follow it at this point i have tried: Booting ubuntu and windows from usb stick, reset computer using windows.

Answer (score 2):

Considering that your error messages says *Debian* and not *Ubuntu*, I'm going to go on a limb and assert that:

1. You had Debian installed on a partition of your internal HDD.
2. You deleted that partition.
3. You also had something like GRUB installed (possibly in your EFI System Partition, since your disk is using a GPT partition scheme) to boot Debian, which you did not remove.
4. Instead of booting from USB or some other bootloader, you are **still** booting from the GRUB bootloader that was installed with Debian, which is designed to try to boot the Debian partition that you have deleted, thereby producing the error you see.

The first thing I think you need to do then is edit your UEFI boot options and make sure that the remnant of the Debian UEFI bootloader is no longer your default boot option. Instead you probably want to point to the Windows UEFI bootloader, which you may find as `bootmgr.efi` possibly in a `microsoft/` subdirectory in your EFI System Partition (how you do that exactly is entirely dependent on the UEFI firmware you use so we can't guide you here), as I strongly suspect that the default `efi/boot/bootx64.efi` of your EFI System Partition is just the Debian GRUB UEFI bootloader.

Then, once you have Windows booting as default, you will need to sort your UEFI firmware options so that you can boot from USB. There again, this is dependent on the UEFI firmware you use, so it will be difficult to tell you how to do just that.

Comment: I can barely undestand what you have written (because I´m not that tech savvy). The fact is that I found on ( :D) a folder named DEBIAN, I deleted this folder. I followed the route and found the filed named _BOOTX64.EFI_ and another one named _grubx64.efi_. Maybe I´m wrong but I think that I should delete the _grubx64.efi_ right as it was what is producing the error. (**On another page**)I set the BIOS to the default setup and windows starts normally tho I still can´t boot ubuntu from the live USB. It shows me the desktop then crashes and starts windows.

Comment: I have edited into the original post the error message that appears when I try to boot ubuntu from the live USB. Hope that helps.